# jQuery - Change all URLs on page include CSS & JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to change all URLs on page, include URLs in CSS/JavaScript files?

This is what I want to do:

HTML file:

```
    Before:
    <a href='../foo.html'></a>
    After:
    <a href='http://my.proxy.server/?url=http://absolute.path.to.page/foo.html'></a>
```

CSS file:

```
    Before:
    .bar {background-image: url(../foo.png);}
    After:
    .bar {background-image: 
        url(http://my.proxy.server/?url=http://absolute.path.to.image/foo.png);}
```

JavaScript file:

```
    Before:
    window.open('../foo.html')
    After:
    window.open('http://my.proxy.server/?url=http://absolute.path.to.page/foo.html')
```

I know it's easy to change URLs of HTML tags with jQuery, but how about URLs in CSS & JavaScript files?

Comment: It would be better to use URL rewriting on the server IMHO...

Comment: I think you should use IIS Rewrite, it can be done using Outbound Rule in IIS. That will take care of HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: How do you want to resolve relative paths like in your example: `../foo.htm`?

Comment: I don't think you can do it dynamically unless you run something on the server, but you can dynamically create css and js files?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("*").each(function(){
   if($(this).attr("href"){
     $(this).attr("href","'http://my.proxy.server/?url=http://absolute.path.to.page/foo.html");
   }
});
```

And repeat that for "src"

Comment: This will only rewrite them all to foo.html!

Comment: Yes , cause question was : Is there any way to change the URL of all links on page

Comment: Foo is usually a placeholder for anything else http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar
besides, your answer does not answer how to change the URL's in CSS files or in JS

Comment: I removed `links` in my post.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert all html to string (something like `content = $("html").html()`)
then make 3 or more regular expressions OR if you need to replace only ../ you can use .split.join: 
`content.split("../").join("http://my.proxy.server/?url=http://absolute.path.to.page/");`
and then back content `$("html").html(content);`

Comment: But how about URLs in css `files` and javascript `files`

Comment: you can load and insert them to content html

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to parse files. I found that change `open` function is a good way to change URL in Javascript. Sample:  `_open=window.open;window.open=function(url){_open(change_url(url))}`